# How do I call an event listener or method whenever an input/control is changed?

Tags: android

I've got a form with a bunch of radio groups, check boxes and text fields. I'm trying to figure out a way to call a method each time any one of these inputs has changed (i.e. radio button selected, check box checked, text field changed). The event listener does not need to be aware of what input was changed.

How should I go about doing this? I've already tried adding an event listener to the layout, but that doesn't work because the event listener is only called when the user taps the background, and it will not fire if any of the inputs are touched. I really don't want to have to create a separate listener for each input.

Any suggestions?

**Update:** I have also tried implementing a `GestureDetector` as described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector#detect-a-subset-of-supported-gestures), but it doesn't seem to be logging anything in my console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that since you want to be notified of different types of events you'll have to create proper listeners for each control type and call update method from them. If you have multiple separate controls of same types you can create abstract class and extend it for each control. Something similar to this:

```
class AbstractTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
   protected OnInputTriggered onInputTriggered;

   public AbstractTextWatcher(OnInputTriggered onInputTriggered){
     this.onInputTriggered = onInputTriggered;
   }
   // afterTextChanged and beforeTextChanged skipped for brevity
   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
     onInputTriggered.onInputTrigerred();
   }
 }
 // sample OnInputTriggered listener
 class OnInputTriggered {
    public void onInputTrigerred(){
      // do stuff you need
    }
 }
```